# Laravel 4.2 - How to preserve form values on select element in raw html

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, laravel-4

When building forms in Laravel but using raw html instead of FROM class I can use something like this to preserve the form data for input element

```
        <input type="text" name="username"{{ (Input::old('username')) ? ' value="' . e(Input::old('username')) . '"' : '' }}>
```

How would I accomplish the same with select drop-down and selected option in a code that looks something like this?

```
        <select name="bday" id="bday">
            <option disabled> </option>
            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
```

I have a working solution that looks like this but I wonder if there is a better, more elegant one

```
         <select name="bday" id="bday">
            <option disabled> </option>
            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
               <option value="{{ $i }}" @if ( Input::old('bday') == $i ) selected @endif > {{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
         </select>
```

Comment: Does this work: `<option value="..." selected="{{ Input.old('bday') === $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>`?

Comment: It sets the value to 31 which is last computed $i

Comment: maybe you should var_dump your old Input to see what you can use

Comment: I can apparently do this <option value="{{ $i }}" if ( Input::old('bday') == $i ) selected endif > {{ $i }}</option>' and I get a workign result.. but it is far from "elegant"

Comment: Well I think that is the only solution here when you don't wanna use the Form helper

Comment: yep. It looks like it. it's ok for now..

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recomemnd using Form helper withing your blade file like : 
`{{ Form::select('bday', $bdays, null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`
By doing so, your options will fill automaticly when validation error occours, and it looks more readable.